# Database information into Facebook Page Tab? XML and cURL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, facebook, curl

I am trying to create a simple Facebook Page Tab that retrieves current information from my database.  I quickly learned that cross-site scripting won't work, as a working demo on the actual website worked great, but produced no results on heroku.

Here is what I have in heroku now. How do I make curl process the page before it returns a result?

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.url.com/output.html');

$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

print $result;
?>
```

Here is the page that creates the formatted XML that is located on my webserver:

```
<?php
require_once('connectDB.php');
$xslt_file = "xmlstyle.xsl";

mysql_select_db($database_DB, $db);

$query = sprintf("SELECT * from db");
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error());

header("Content-type: text/xml");
$XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
if ($xslt_file) $XML .= "<?xml-stylesheet href=\"$xslt_file\" type=\"text/xsl\" ?>";

// root node
$XML .= "<result>\n";
// rows
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {    
  $XML .= "\t<row>\n"; 
  $i = 0;
  // cells
  foreach ($row as $cell) {
    // Escaping illegal characters - not tested actually ;)
    $cell = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace("\"", "&quot;", $cell);
    $col_name = mysql_field_name($result,$i);
    // creates the "<tag>contents</tag>" representing the column
    $XML .= "\t\t<" . $col_name . ">" . $cell . "</" . $col_name . ">\n";
    $i++;
  }
  $XML .= "\t</row>\n"; 
 }
$XML .= "</result>\n";
// output the whole XML string
echo $XML;
?>
```

I'm sure I'm over complicating this whole thing, but it has been somewhat enjoyable to try to make it work.  If there is a much easier way to get the same result, I'm all ears.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the RETURNTRANSFER option:

```
//Set curl to return the page instead of sending it to the browser
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

**References**

- [curl manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)
- [PHP curl binding](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)